# How to find the workflow name that was trigged by my telegram-notifier workflow

Tags: github-actions, workflow

I created a workflow called telegram-notifier(.yaml). the role of this workflow is to trigger other running workflows [workflowA,workflowB,workflowC].

If one of these workflows completes my telegram-notifier workflow should raise and send me a notification in telegram with name of the workflow that finished.

My question is how I get the name of the workflow that has been completed (the one that telegram-notifier has triggered it).

telegram-notifier.yaml

```
name: telegram-notifier
on: 
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [workflowA,workflowB,workflowC]
    types:
      - completed
```

until now I send these info and all that I need is to know which workflow was trigged.
Some output that the telegram-notifier sended to me.

```
Created at: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.created_at }}
User : ${{ github.actor }}.
Repository: ${{ github.repository }}.
Status: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.status }}
Conclusion: Task is done with ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion }}
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer idk if i need to leave this post or not
the answer is :
workflow name : ${{ github.event.workflow_run.name }}

and if you want the path :
workflow name : ${{ github.event.workflow_run.path }}